# Magento - Don't charge tax for shipping

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a flat rate of $6 for all orders, and I don't want to charge any taxes on the shipping cost.

I noticed by default Magento is setup to charge tax on the shipping cost as well.
I would like to disable that feature, but can't figure it out in the admin panel.

I've attached a screenshot of my tax settings.

What do I need to change to stop charging tax on the shipping cost?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the "Tax Class for Shipping" to "None" then "Save Config".

Refer below link for more detailed insight:

http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/system-tax-settings